# 'SwaggerGenOptions' does not contain a definition for 'SerializeAsV2'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm trying to use swaggergen tools, so I configure my services:

```
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SerializeAsV2 = true;
            c.CustomOperationIds(apiDescription => {
                return apiDescription.TryGetMethodInfo(out MethodInfo methodInfo) ? methodInfo.Name : null;
            });
```

I have Swashbuckle.AspNetCore and Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Newtonsoft installed in my nuget package manager

Why does the c.SerializeAsV2 has a red squiggly: "'SwaggerGenOptions' does not contain a definition for 'SerializeAsV2'" I can't find anything on this at all in google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move it to the `Configure` method:

```cs
app.UseSwagger(c =>
{
    c.SerializeAsV2 = true;
});
```

Reference: [Serialize Swagger in the 2.0 format](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/README.md#serialize-swagger-in-the-20-format)

Comment: Even after adding this to the Configure method, it still generates a json document in version 3.0.  Any pointers as to why this might be happening?